# Load content while scrolling in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I am simply uploading images and displaying them in gsp view. What I want to do now is whenever I scroll down that gsp view images must load.

Someone told me to do a ajax call using jQuery.

Please help.

Comment: We love to help you but How? you have not posted any code to look for, If you really need help then help yourself with posting some code here.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way to achieve something like this is to use an existing jQuery plugin.  I would recommend talking a look at the below plugins that should work well with grails...

- [jQuery Plugin: Infinite Scroll](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/)
- [jQuery Plugin: Scroll Pagination](http://andersonferminiano.com/jqueryscrollpagination/)
- [jQuery Plugin: autobrowser](http://msjolund.github.com/autobrowse/)

These plugins require you to know a little bit about jQuery so don't expect to just copy and past the code into your gsp pages and have everything work.